# android camera setPictureSize doesn't work

Tags: android

To reduce the capacity of the picture, I used setPictureSize as shown below to size the picture, but after doing camera.takePicture() there was nothing else.
What can I do to reduce the size of the pictures taken from the camera?

```
Camera camera = getCameraInstance();
final Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setPictureSize(640,320);
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have set the parameters after you have set the picture size.
And you can also reduce jpeg quality if you want to reduce the image size even more.
this is how I did it

```
mCamera = getCameraInstance();
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
Camera.Size size = sizes.get(0);
for(int i=0;i<sizes.size();i++)
   {
         if(sizes.get(i).width >= 800 && sizes.get(i).width<=1000){
             size = sizes.get(i);
    }
}
params.setJpegQuality(30);
params.setPictureSize(size.width,size.height);
mCamera.setParameters(params);
```